# expiry date in odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

How to calculate expiry date in odoo 10 and how to notify to customers from email/sms before 10 days?

for example:-

If expiry date is near, the customer gets notification through mail or sms.

Can anyone suggest any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a scheduler it should run everyday. It should calculate the expiry dates which are ending in next 10 days. For those records you have to trigger the mail.

1. Create a scheduler
2. Find the expiry dates
3. Create email template
4. Trigger Email

Please refer sale subscription it has subscription expiry reminder

Comment: I have set all parameters in scheduler but i have not getting any mail notification.